# Get id of $(this)

Tags: jquery

I try to get the id of elements that I searched in content:

```
$headings = jQuery('.kb-content').find('h2');
jQuery($headings).each(function() {
    jQuery('#kb-postnav .nav').append('<li><a href="'+$(this).attr('id')+'">'+$(this).text()+'</a></li>');
});
```

But the result for the id is undefined.
I searched long time in google and found much "answeres" but non of the worked:

```
this.id;
$(obj).attr('id');
...
```

**Edit**: Sorry my fault, found the issue: the id for the h2 element is created after my functions. But this function does also add extra content to the h2 element. So I want to get the id of the parent now.
Like

```
<div id="test">
    <h2>This is a test</h2>
</div>
```

So I want to get the parent AFTER the find('h2'), when the element is already in the found list.

Comment: you can just do this.id

Comment: Already tried that (read question). The result is just a empty href=""

Comment: Then the element you found has no id.

Comment: It has a id: http://fs1.directupload.net/images/150722/d7xxr9ri.png

Comment: i agree with @RobertMcKee. it seems the element which you are trying to find deosnt contains any id. Please re check.

Comment: See comment I wrote above you

Comment: This works. What's the problem? Maybe your `h2` elements don't have ids

Comment: [Evidence that it works](http://jsfiddle.net/purmou/sypvqwLb/). Post your HTML, that might help. :)

Comment: HTML can be found here until I create a fiddle: http://area51.zoker.me/freelancer/support/kb/documentation/

Comment: Found the issue: the element id is assigned AFTER my function by another function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The element you found has no id, because `this.id` works just fine:

```js
jQuery('.kb-content h2').parent().each(function() { 
    alert(this.id);
});
/* Alternative
jQuery('.kb-content h2').each(function() { 
    alert(this.parentElement.id);
});
*/
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="parentid" class="kb-content">
  <h2 id="id1">Title</h2>
</div>
<div id="jb-postnav">
  <div class="nav"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Found the issue: the element id is assigned AFTER my function by another function. Is there any way to get the id of the parent element?

Comment: `this.parentElement.id`

Comment: `$(this).parent().attr("id")` or `$(this).parent()[0].id`

Comment: Works well :) Thank you!

Comment: The answer by @tymeJV should also work as well.  His uses jQuery's selectors and methods, while `parentElement` is the pure javascript way of doing it.  Alternatively, you could just do this: `jQuery('.kb-content h2').parent().each(function() { ... });` and inside the code block, `this` will refer to the parent of the h2's inside .kb-contents.